# JavaScript : unable to merge two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, push, concatenation

I'm not a veteran of JavaScript and I have a little problem :

In an AngularJS controller, I get 2 arrays from a WebService of the form `[{"id":"1", "name":"aname1"}, {"id":"2", "name":"aname2"}]`. They have both the same structure (this shouldn't be important).

With `concat()` or `push()` I'm unable to merge these arrays together, and I don't understand why.

I tried

```
var arrayS = Service.list();           // Get data from WebService
var arrayAE = ActeurExterne.list();    // Idem
var arrayRes = arrayS.concat(arrayAE);
$scope.acteurs = arrayRes;
```

In my AngularJS app, the array `acteurs` is empty (if I displays it outside a `ng-repeat` loop, it displays `[]` while arrayS and arrayAE display their contents)

And the same logic with :

```
array1.push.apply(array1, array2);
```

I tried to push elements of array2 one by one in a for loop, same result.

Nothing worked. Why?

Comment: please provide code what you tried

Comment: `array1.push.apply(array1, array2);` is working for me. `concat` is also working, though it return a new array: `array1 = array1.concat(array2);`.

Comment: Do you **really** think `concat` or `push` doesn't work? Please state what is the problem with a code fragment... for sure your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Why do you mark it as angular js question?

Comment: @Pierre: when you say "Nothing worked" - what actually happened? What result did you get from the code you tried, and what result were you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually merging the arrays correctly and both methods would work (provided like others said that you use the return value of `concat`), but the result is empty because you're doing it when the answers from the ajax requests didn't arrive yet and the arrays are still empty.

When making ajax requests you must manipulate the result inside the success callback function, not at the same level of the ajax request code; for example

```
var myvec = [];
$.getjson(request_url, function(data) {
    myvec = data;
});
process(myvec);
```

will NOT work, because it's attempting to use the content of `myvec` right after the request has been submitted but before the reply arrived. Correct code is instead:

```
$.getjson(request_url, function(data) {
    // This code is executed when the data arrives from the server
    process(data);
});
```

If you need to concatenate the results of two async queries you must either chain them (make the second query only once the first returned) or you must wait for the second one to complete:

```
// First solution, simple but slower (waits for first reply
// before making second request)
$.getjson(request_url_1, function(data_1) {
    $.getjson(request_url_2, function(data_2) {
        process(data_1.concat(data_2));
    });
});
```

or

```
// Second solution; starts both requests and waits for both
// of them to complete before doing the processing

var count = 0;
var res = [];
function handle_data(data) {
    res = res.concat(data);
    count += 1;
    if (count == 2) {
        process(res);
    }
}

$.get(request_url_1, handle_data);
$.get(request_url_2, handle_data);
```

This crazy guess is simply coming from the frequency that this kind of error has in beginner code.

Comment: This seems to be the reason. With arrays assigned statically, concat and push work fine. What solution do you suggest for my problem ?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesLeDévéhat: see edit for a simple explanation of asynchronous logic needed for ajax.

Answer (score 6):

`concat()` will return a new array, not concat to the `this`. So:

```
var a=[1,2,3];
var b=[4,5,6];
var c=a.concat(b);
// a is still [1,2,3]
// c is [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: I doubt that's the real issue: the OP says "I tried to push elements of array2 one by one in a for loop, same result". I think the question is missing the real problem...

Answer (score 2):

Did you assign the result to another variable? For example:

```
var result = array1.concat(array2);
```

The `.concat()` method returns a new Array with the concatenated elements.

[MDN Documentation on `Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
var newArray= array1.concat(array2);
```