# How merge two objects array in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, merge, append

I want to append following object array with existing one in angulajs for implementing load more feature.

ie,appending AJAX response with existing one each time.

I have one variable, `$scope.actions` which contains following `JSON` data,

```
    {
    "total": 13,
    "per_page": 2,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 7,
    "next_page_url": "http://invoice.local/activities/?page=2",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2108,
            "action_type_id": 202,
            "user_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2108,
            "action_type_id": 202,
            "user_id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to append following `JSON` response each time this variable.

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2108,
            "action_type_id": 202,
            "user_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2108,
            "action_type_id": 202,
            "user_id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried with `$scope.actions.data.concat(data.data);`

but it is not working and getting following error message

`$scope.actions.data.concat is not a function`

Comment: Angular has both `extend` and `copy` that copies objects

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765283/javascript-unable-to-merge-two-arrays

Comment: Since new variable is exactly the same as `data` property in first sample, some clarification would help

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `angular.extend(dest, src1, src2,...);`

In your case it would be :

```
angular.extend($scope.actions.data, data);
```

See documentation here :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Otherwise, if you only get new values from the server, you can do the following

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    $scope.actions.data.push(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: can't you give more info?

Comment: `angular.extend($scope.actions, data); it is replacing not appending :(

Comment: When trying second method,getting error `Error: $scope.actions.data.push is not a function`

Comment: I think you should try to do this `angular.extend({}, $scope.actions.data, data); `. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend. This helps me a lot and this also works for me.

Comment: angular.extend and angular.merge is just replacing the values and not merging. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: angular.extend() is a shallow copy and will fail in the general case (arrays of arbitrarily complex objects).  angular.merge() implements a deep copy, but also failed during cursory testing...  I opted for the direct solution: src.forEach(function (x) { dst.push(x); }); to merge src into dst.

Answer (score 29):

This works for me :

```
$scope.array1 = $scope.array1.concat(array2)
```

In your case it would be :

```
$scope.actions.data = $scope.actions.data.concat(data)
```

Comment: @davidH This is only the correct answer if you want to just plonk two arrays together. Ideal if the keys of the array are just an arbitrary index number. However, for the actual example in the question, each item is being returned with a specific ID, so merge or extend are better here to avoid duplicates in the resulting array.

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm using $scope.actions.data in an ng-repeat, the value in console is updating but not in the view file.

Answer (score 4):

```
$scope.actions.data.concat is not a function
```

same problem with me but i solve the problem by

```
 $scope.actions.data = [].concat($scope.actions.data , data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
var a=[{a:4}], b=[{b:5}]

angular.merge(a,b) // [{a:4, b:5}]
```

Tested on angular 1.4.1

Comment: Unlike extend(), merge() recursively descends into object properties of source objects, performing a deep copy.