# Anyway to `angular.copy(..., ...)` without replacing data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular factory with a function that loads a range of items from a list via an API. So if I wanted to load the first 10 I would say something like `getRange(0, 10)`. Once the JSON returns from the API, I copy the items over to a local model using `angular.copy`... But how do I load the next 10 and copy the list items over, without deleting the old ones. Apparently, I can't continue to use `angular.copy` because it deletes the old items and then copies over the new items.

Any guidance?

Comment: Are your items an `Array`?

Comment: Yes... I am using an Array.

Comment: You can use angular.extend.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948680/how-merge-two-objects-array-in-angularjs

Comment: Show the code if you can so it's easier to make a more relevant example in the answer

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions Grateful?

Comment: I ended up copying the items over manually!

Answer (score 0):

You can think something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('demoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = []; // data from factory.
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // for demo filling it up
    $scope.arr.push({ item: i }); // just like this
  }
  $scope.newArr = []; // the new item array; 
  $scope.len = $scope.newArr.length || 10;
  $scope.getItems = getItems;

  function getItems() {
    for (var i = $scope.len - 10; i < $scope.len; i++) {
      $scope.newArr.push(angular.copy($scope.arr[i]))
    }
    $scope.len += 10;
  }

});
```

#### [Take a look at the plnkr here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/GIcCNtuo5vgtSATsgry2?p=preview)